# My arrival at Heathrow Airport is one day earlier than the start date of the validity of my UK visa, can I wait at the airport until the next day?

Tags: visas, lhr

I am an Indonesian national and planning to visit UK on July 21. But for some reason the embassy give me a UK visa with the validity date start from July 22. I already bought a ticket with the arrival time at Heathrow on July 21 at 09.30. Since it's a promo tickets, I can't change the date and refund it.

My question is, is it possible for me to pass through the border control with my visa, which won't be valid yet at the time? Or if it's not possible, can I wait at the airport and go pass the border control after midnight on July 22? Is there any transit hotel or other facility that I can get some rest while waiting?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Most likely the airline will not allow you to board unless you have appropriate documentation for entering the UK _on the day of arrival_. Your best bet is to contact the consulate to enquire whether the later validity date is a clerical error they can fix for you.

Comment: Please see the linked article as it is directly applicable.  I emphatically suggest taking @HenningMakholm comment to hear also

Comment: *July 21 at 09.30*. Do you expect to wait 14 hours 30 minutes between the bridge and immigration without anyone noticing something is odd?

Comment: I've never been to Heathrow Airport before. So I'm still wondering where the passport check is after I step off the plane. Is it right away after I step off the plane, or is there any transit area or waiting room or any other facility between them?

Comment: You cannot wait in the transit area for 14 hours and 30 minutes until your visa becomes valid. The most likely scenario is that the airline agent (or their computer) notices your visa won't be valid and refuses to let you board the plane. Otherwise, you will attract negative attention from security when you arrive. You need to contact the office that issued the visa and ask them to correct it or figure out a way to not arrive until your visa is valid.

Comment: @ZachLipton https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98326/do-i-have-to-pass-immigration-check-to-go-to-transit-hotel-at-heathrow

Comment: What generally seems to happen in UK airports is that _all passengers from international arrivals_ are confined to sterile corridors (no waiting areas!) until they reach the queues for either immigration or transfer security.