# Do I have to pass immigration check to go to Transit Hotel at Heathrow?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, lhr

I will arrive at Terminal 2 Heathrow Airport and am willing to spend some time at a transit hotel. I found there is Yotel at Terminal 4. do I have to pass through immigration control to get there?

Comment: If this question is related to your earlier question( https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/98315/my-arrival-at-heathrow-airport-is-one-day-earlier-than-the-start-date-of-the-val) about Arriving early to LHR and waiting it out before your visa becomes valid please do not try this (assumed workaround) scheme it will backfire badly and you might even be refused entry to UK. You can not stay at a transit hotel when you are *arriving*. You do not have any boarding pass for a further flight.

Comment: Also. The airline will not let you board from your home country when it knows your visa will not be valid when you reach. Instead of looking for workarounds play by the book and visit the airline office explain the problem to them and see what is the best adjustment they can make

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the Yotel at Heathrow T4 is [landside](http://www.yotel.com/en/hotels/london-heathrow-airport/faqs/yotelair-london-heathrow/do-i-need-a-visa-to-access-yotel), and you would thus have to clear immigration to stay there.

Comment: As I wrote recently elsewhere, only the Yotel at Schiphol and Paris (CDG) is on the airside and the CDG one is limited to certain kinds of flights. The Yotel and Gatwick and Heathrow are both landside, yes. And the LHR one is far, noone ever goes to T4 ;) everything now is either T2 or T5.